# Does pressing L give you items faster?

Tags: mario-kart-8

In Mario Kart, you have to wait a few seconds before receiving an item from an item box. As a kid, I always thought mashing L sped up this excruciatingly long (2-5 second) process.

However, there are a few other ways I could imagine Mario Kart handles this operation. The waiting period could be determined by:

- Your current placement
- Your currently/previously held items
- Your character/kart (this may only be a factor in Double Dash)
- Randomly

**Is it possible to influence how fast your receive your item, or is it determined by other factors?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get your items faster by pressing the item button to interrupt the roulette. I don't know the exact numbers, but it's pretty simple: Normally you get an item after a certain period of time, and you can press the button to receive it earlier, though there is a minimum roulette time (it can't be instant).

In MK8 specifically, this is the only pure factor in roulette time: it's fixed, but you can interrupt it earlier after a point. However, when playing online, the roulette doesn't stop until it successfully hears from all other players that they know what your item is. As a result it will roll slower in games with more laggy opponents.